# Ember - how do I do simplest possible routes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Ok, being minimalist, I have an index.html that has

```
<html>
  <body>
    hello world
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="lists">
      <h1>in route lists</h1>
    </script> 
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and an app.js with

```
var App = window.App = Ember.Application.create({
   LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('lists');
});
```

Shouldn't that be enough to get me a page with 'in route lists' when I navigate to AppURL/lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is enough to get you a page with 'in route lists'. The page will be at `APP_URL/#/lists` though as by default ember uses the browsers hash for routing. If you wish to use hashless urls you need to tell your router to use the HTML5 history API:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

You can read more about this here:
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/

and find a JSBin to play about here:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/seweqedi/2/

Comment: @mcktimo And if wanted to be on the default route your could define your resource as
`this.resource('lists', {path: '/'});`